# ¿Cómo usar variables de tipo get concatenadas en sentencia Update de MySQL desde Python?

Tags: python

Soy nueva programando y tengo conocimientos básicos de Python. Quiero actualizar datos en mi BD desde una interfaz de Python pero me sale el siguiente error:

> TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?`

```
def modificar():
#VARIABLES QUE GUARDAN LO QUE SE OBTIENE DEL ENTRY
    self.m = self.mat.get()
    self.carre = self.ca.get()
    self.n = self.na.get()
    self.apa = self.ap.get()
    self.ama = self.am.get()
    self.s = self.sem.get()
    self.t = self.tel.get()
    self.c = self.con.get()
#OBTENGO LA MATRICULA Y LA GUARDO EN LA VARIABLE
    cursor.execute("SELECT a.id_alumno, a.id_matricula FROM alumnos AS a 
    WHERE a.id_matricula = '" + self.infor[0] + "';")
    consul = cursor.fetchone()
    self.idmodificar = str(consul[1])
#EJECUTO LA ACTUALIZACIÓN CONCATENANDO LAS VARIABLES ANTERIORES
    sql = "UPDATE alumnos SET\
         id_matricula = " + self.m + ",\
         id_carrera = " + self.carre + ",\
         nombre =  '" + self.n + "',\
         apellido_paterno = '" + self.apa + "',\
         apellido_materno = '" + self.ama + "',\
         semestre = " + self.s + ",\
         telefono = " + self.t + ",\
         contraseña = '" + self.c + "'\
         WHERE id_matricula = '" + self.idmodificar + "';"  # AQUÍ ESTÁ EL PROBLEMA
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conexion.commit()
    messagebox.showinfo("ACTUALIZACIÓN EXITOSA!!", "        Datos actualizados correctamente. \n\n")`
```

Este método se acciona al oprimir el botón Guardar Actualización.
De antemano ¡Gracias!

Comment: No tienes mas informacion sobre el error?  Por ejemplo en que linea esta

Comment: ¿Todos los métodos `get` se aplican sobre un `tkinter.Entry` seguro? Si es así no veo de donde puede venir el error con lo que muestras en la línea que marcas. `tkinter.Entry.get` retorna siempre una cadena, no `int`. A todo esto, ¿usas tkinter verdad? Coloca la traza completa del error a ver si es de ayuda. Por cierto, usas `self` en las variables, pero modificar no es un método de instancia...

Comment: @alanfcm No da más información, sólo me indica que está en la sentencia Where, donde puse el comentario "Aquí está el problema"

Comment: Ya resolví el problema implementando esto en la sentencia Update:             sql = "UPDATE alumnos as a SET a.id_matricula = %s, a.id_carrera = %d, a.nombre = '%s', a.apellido_paterno = '%s', a.apellido_materno = '%s', a.semestre = %s, a.telefono = %s, \
            a.contraseña = '%s' WHERE a.id_matricula = %s" % (self.m, self.carre, self.n, self.apa, self.ama, self.s, self.t, self.c, self.idmodificar)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias :D